# Диалоговое окно обзор папок в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, диалог

Если использую QFileDialog открывается большое окно. А мне нужно маленькое, как на картинке.

[image: Обзор папок]

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, окно из вопроса `Qt` не вызвать, более близкий вариант этот:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication([])

dir_name = Qt.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    None,
    "Open Directory",
    Qt.QDir.currentPath(),
    Qt.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | Qt.QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks
)
print(dir_name)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно, конечно, повторить через `Qt` такой диалог или попробовать вызывать через `WinAPI` тот диалог, но зачем? Этот диалог неудобный – без возможности копирования/вставки пути им неудобно пользоваться